# How do I settle a 2-month-old who wants to be carried all the time?

Tags: infant, newborn, aggression, soothing

My child is 2 months ++ old and wants to be held and carried around or they kick and yell. Cuddling them isn't sufficient, you need to be stood up and moving around. It's boring, tiring and makes you look like a lunatic if your neighbours notice!

I'm happy with the carrying but walking for a long period of time is rather tough. May I know how to encourage baby to be held/cuddled only and not walk around?

When I carry him and sit down, he will kick his legs aggressively.

Comment: When you say, "walk him", I presume you mean, push him in a stroller, is that correct? What is the problem you're having with him in a stroller? At 2 months, he doesn't have a choice in his mode of transportation, so I'm not quite clear on what you're asking.

Comment: Or are you talking about "I have to not only lift him up, but also keep walking with him in my arms"?

Comment: @anongoodnurse Sounds vaguely like they want the child to sit still in their arms?  Kinda guessing though.

Comment: I've had this.  Basically the child wants to be held and carried around or they kick and yell.  Cuddling them isn't sufficient, you need to be stood up and moving around.  It's boring, tiring and makes you look like a lunatic if your neighbours notice!  (as mine did...)

Answer (score 6):

Look into [babywearing](http://www.babywearingadvice.co.uk/anatomy.htm).

I have been doing this with my daughter since she was born. Nothing is more easy for me or her. I can still use my hands and yet she can be close to me and follow around with what I'm doing.

As with all things related to babies, it took some time to get used to it.

Comment: Babywearing it's so comfortable if you do it right! My son has 1yo and 2 months and we didn't get a stroller (too much money, too much space, we live in the 4th floor and the building did not have a elevator).

Answer (score 2):

My eldest did this, particularly at night.  I remember spending many nights pacing around the house carrying my little one to soothe her, only for her to get upset when I stopped.  Mine liked to be upright, with a gentle rocking motion and being able to stretch her legs (which I suspect is the main reason for the kicking when you stop.)

There isn't a huge amount you can do about it and it's one of those movements that is hard to replicate.  Babywearing will help (I loved my cloth sling, it was fantastic) and if nothing else it will at least free up the use of your arms - but it's unlikely to do anything about the walking around because your gait (walk) clearly provides the right rocking motion for him.

Give it another 8-10 weeks and things should change (things can change a huge amount from month to month or even week to week at this stage) without you having to do anything other than keep them clean, comfy, and fed - they will get to the rest on their schedule.

Comment: Seconding this, we had the same issue. We ended up tracking it down to a dairy sensitivity, but in the thick of it we also used an exercise ball. Sitting on it and bouncing with her in our arms, while also exhausting, was at least a different motion than walking. So you could do a half hour walking in circles, half hour on the ball, ad infinum.